# Copiar imagen de un modelo a otro

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

tengo una duda actualmente estoy usando carrierwave y el storage de google para almacenar imágenes, pero quería saber si hay una forma de tomar la imagen del modelo a y asignársela a otro modelo para que guarde esa misma imagen.

actualmente intente esto pero sin resultados:

```
modelo1 = Modelo1.last

modelo2.picture_name = modelo1.file_name
modelo2.picture_content_type = modelo1.file_content_type
modelo2.picture_size = modelo1.file_size
modelo2.picture_updated_at = modelo1.file_updated_at
modelo2.original_picture_name = modelo1.original_file_name

modelo2.save
```

Comment: si puedes poner el codigo del Modelo1 para ver como estas usando carrierwave, pero basicamente falta copiar la url de la imagen donde se guardo al subirse o el contenido de la misma si se guardo en el storage

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bueno el problema era a nivel de Base de datos, me daba deadlock al general la copia por un proceso independiente de la app.

Answer (score 0):

Podrias usar el método `dup` para asignar todos los atributos del modelo1 al modelo2 y despues sobreescribir los que necesites cambiar en el modelo2

tu codigo quedaria algo asi:

```
modelo1 = Modelo1.last
modelo2 = modelo1.dup
# si requieres cambiar algo del modelo2 puedes hacerlo aqui y despues guardas
modelo2.save
```